# How to pixelize an image without antialiasing effect in paint.net

Tags: paint.net

I have an image that I would like to pixelize, but after pixelizing I have colors with transparency (antialiased).

How would I prevent this?

[image]

Comment: What does the imgae look like before pixelizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying the effect, if you save or export the image as .gif format with transparency, the *semi-transparency* disappears, since the .gif format only supports one color 100% transparent.

The smoothing pixels are transformed into flat colors blurred to white.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Paint(dot)net user, however the following steps should work in almost any raster image editing software generally.  Begin with the original unedited image, but instead of applying a filter to pixelise, do it manually as follows:

1. Check the size of the image, and write down the width and height in pixels.
2. Scale/resize the image down to something like 30px wide or 30px high, but switch of the interpolation.  In Photoshop this is called "nearest neighbour", I think it's also the same in Paint(dot)net, and in GIMP it's called "none".  These options are in the scale/resize image dialog.
3. Finally, scale the image back up to the original size, using the same interpolation setting.